# Database or Text file for single value file per individual user?

Tags: php, mysql, database, text-files, data-storage

I am planning to create an online game where user moves in a random path. I need to keep track of current location of player in the map. Since there will many concurrent players that keep moving around, there will be too many values to keep track of.

I was wondering if I need to save the last accessed coordinates by player, is it better to keep a text file for each player that save a single location value, or save all players' locations in one database table?

I know this might seem like an old question, I have already checked similar questions in Stackoferflow, such as:

- [database vs. flat files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356851/database-vs-flat-files)
- [Is it faster to access data from files or a database server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147902/is-it-faster-to-access-data-from-files-or-a-database-server)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23124/whats-better-faster-mysql-or-filesystem

But in those questions the answers were broad and general. I need a specific answer: Single file per user and single value by file, is better than a single table for all users for very frequent update/read?

Comment: "Since there will many concurrent players that keep moving around, there will be too many values to keep track of." I would question the validity of this assertion. If there were a billion players, that would equate to a billion rows. An RDBMs can handle a billion rows.

Comment: To be realistic the game wouldn't reach that scale, I'd say few thousands tops.

Comment: You can't even up technology inefficiencies (php, http) with clever persistence solution.