# NodeJS storing large object - JSON file vs Database

Tags: node.js, json, database, object

I am loading a few big JSON data from 3rd party API on server startup and write them into .JSON files (150mb json files), loading it into an object whenever I need to use it.

The thing is, I am not sure this is the right and efficient way to do so. Should I use a database instead? If yes, could you mention which one to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

glad to answer your question.

Modern databases are already able to keep up with large file sizes, so in this case size would not be an issue.

However, the issue regarding performance is that it still depends on the usage and purpose of the application.

For example, sometimes the application might require content caching, in this case most databases already have this function built-in, however, there are also applications where this won't apply.

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147902/is-it-faster-to-access-data-from-files-or-a-database-server) also discusses the comparison of disk storage and database storage, there are lots of good answers in there, I hope it will help.